# Java XPath interpreting '-' as minus with GUIDs

Tags: java, xpath

I'm writing an XPath expression in Java, and am trying to grab all elements with a particular GUID. Basically, I'm doing:

`(NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//object[guid=" + guid + "]", objectDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);`

with a GUID:

```
eb52a56c-2a16-4256-ab0c-523cb6d19a3f
```

XPath throws me an error:

```
eb52a56c-2a16-4256-ab0c-523cb6d19a3f could not be formatted to a number!
```

and I assume that this is because of the dashes. Am I wrong? If not, is there a way to escape them? I found mention of escaping characters in XPath via Google, but nobody mentioned dashes.

Thanks,
Cody

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote it. "//object[guid='" + guid + "']"

Answer (score 2):

As EJP says, it needs to be in quotes.

However, constructing XPath expressions this way by string concatenation is the wrong approach. Use an expression like

```
xpath.evaluate("//object[guid=$guid]")
```

and bind the variable $guid using the XPath API (by creating a VariableResolver).

There are many benefits: optimization, clarity of code, avoiding injection attacks, avoiding inexplicable behaviour that can only be diagnosed by asking questions on StackOverflow, etc.